# SSRS - white space issue in column group

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, removing-whitespace

I have a row group in my report that I'm using in the page header using the approach in this article:  [Reporting Services - Group Name in Page Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632215/reporting-services-group-name-in-page-header)  However, I can't find a way to NOT SHOW the column in the Tablix AND not have white space in the report where the hidden column is.  Anyone?  I've been searching for hours now :)

[image: Preview Mode]

[image: Design Mode]

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the column to something minuscule (0.00001 for example)?

Comment: Not the most glamorous solution, but it will do.  This just seems like such a normal thing to do - hard to believe it can't be done the "right" way.  thanks.

Comment: One of the cons to SSRS design, but I've yet to run across a system that doesn't have a similar situation in one way or another.

Comment: it would be good if you could show a screenshot of the hidden column in design view and in preview.

Comment: Images attached for what they are worth.  Basically, there is white space reserved to the left of the first non-hidden field (Board).

Comment: Best solution you have to delete the hidden column, it ask you to delete group or column only. So go for column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already did that - it leaves whitespace.  I finally just gave up and slid the column width to the minimum so that it doesn't show.